# what does np.reshape(2, -1)?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm making the exercise 8 of that list: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/101-numpy-exercises-python/

the exercise says that a array is given by the code `a = np.arange(10).reshape(2, -1)` and then, if we print array a we gonna see he is `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`.

why the array is reshaped like that, i dont understand, can someone please explain to me?

since now i thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method reshape, like the name suggests, reshapes a numpy array to the given dimensions. `np.arange(10)` gives you an array of shape (1, 10). If you use the reshape function, it expects the dimensions (or a tuple containing them) for example (2, 5). However, the -1 means that it will take the right dimension to fit your first argument. In your case, the first dimension is 2, which means the second dimension should be 5 so the reshape function fills this in automatically. That's why your output is of shape (2, 5). You can find all the information you need over [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know ,how reshape method works in numpy.If not ,you can follow this link https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html to know more about it.
But if you know how it works,the explanation concerning

```
a = np.arange(10).reshape(2, -1)
```

is we create an array of 10 elements(0...9) using arange method.Then we transfrom this array into a matrix using reshape.The first parameter 2 is the number of lines of the matrix we want to create.And the second parameter -1 is used to infer one missing length from the other(here the number of columns).

Excuse me for my english.I'm not native speaker